# TailwindCSS styles are not applied in my Next js app

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I have created a Next js app. As they said in their documentation, I integrated TailwindCSS into my project. Everything went well. However, the result I got was a web page where no TailwindCSS styles were applied on.

I will provide the files that I think are causing this issue.

I would appreciate it if someone could clarify where I am wrong.

**Index.js file**

```
return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="px-4" style={{maxWidth: "1600px"}}>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2> Test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
       )
```

**postcss.config.js file:**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
   "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
   "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
   extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  }
```

**globals.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Tailwind does not apply any classes (including their reset classes) until you use one of their utility classes in your code

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? Or direct me to a thread.

Comment: `@`SinaRahimi the elaboration is in my answer

Answer (score 4):

A missing import line `import '../styles/globals.css'` ( My case ) at the beginning of the **_app.js** file could cause the issue.

I had mistakenly commented out this line in my **_app.js** file, and everything started to work out fine when I fixed it.

It is also clear that the **content** property of the **module.exports** object in **tailwind.config** file should be set properly, as explained above a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tailwind.config.js` needs a `content` field so that Tailwind knows where to look for their utility classes being called.

```js
content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
```

Here's my entire config:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Tailwind does not apply any classes (including their reset classes) until you use one of their utility classes in your code, so if it doesn't know you used any of them then no styles will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You should add following code in your tailwind.config.js file

````
module.exports = {
content: [
 "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
 "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
],
theme: {
 extend: {},
},
plugins: [],
} ```

It should work fine.
````

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. add a `watch` script to your `scripts` in `package.json` file

**Make sure to give it the correct path for your input/output css files**

```json
"scripts": {
    "watch": "npx tailwindcss -i src/input.css -o dist/output.css --watch"
 }
```

2: run it:

```bash
npm run watch
```

Comment: How should I determine the correct path for my input/output file?

Comment: if you don't have the output file tailwind will create that for you automatically, but for the input file, you can put it in an `src` folder for example.

Comment: Since I am using the Next js framework, I don't have the **src** folder. Also, I don't have the **input.css** file which I think is the cause of my issue

Comment: just create them

Answer (score 0):

your tailwind.config.js doesnt have the code connecting it to the pages you want processed. you should include this.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", //path to components/pages
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", //path to components/pages
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

the code above (minus the comments) is from their website,

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: Do you know what those stars stand for?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems my problem belongs to somewhere else